# read-only git mirror of an svn repository

Tags: svn, git, post-commit

What would be the best way to set up a read-only git mirror of an existing svn repository, and set up post-commit hooks such that whenever someone commits to svn, the git mirror is automatically updated? Mainly, I'd like to run git-svn clone just once, on the server, and then let people just check out from git without having to git-svn clone the entire svn repository themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do that on a project that uses SVN (pushing to a public repository on github). I don't have a SVN commit hook, but this on a cron job:

```
#!/bin/bash

repo=/path/to/my-mirror.git
lockfile="$repo/cron-lock"

if ! lockfile -r1 "$lockfile";then
        exit 1
fi

export GIT_DIR=$repo
# update refs/remotes/git-svn:
git svn fetch -q
# make 'master' match the git-svn branch:
git fetch "$repo" refs/remotes/git-svn:refs/heads/master
# publish to github
git push github master

rm -f "$lockfile"
```

If you trigger this from a SVN commit hook instead of a cron job, it should work.

Of course, you need to set up a remote called `github` using `git remote add github [...]`. The git repository I am using is a "bare" repository (see `git init --bare`).

Answer (score 2):

The best way to set up an Svn/Git mirror (writable) would be to use [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) - this is a tool specifically developed for this task. Disclaimer: I am the developer of this tool.

Comment: Besides, SubGit 2.0 no longer needs local access to the Subversion repository and could build a writable Git mirror of a remote Subversion repository too (see http://subgit.com/eap).

Comment: @AlexanderKitaev Please note that you must disclose your affiliation when linking to a product or another website. I see from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13288270/2057919) that you developed SubGit. I have edited this answer to reflect that. In the future, please be sure to mention your connection if you link to SubGit.